# Text editor capable of wrapping text at syllable boundaries

Tags: text-editor

I am looking for a text editor that can break lines at syllable boundaries and not only at word boundaries, the latter being the default for products like Microsoft Word or Notepad++.

My purpose is to have nicely laid out texts, like in printed books, as I am not completely satisfied with the looks of Justified Text.

I am specifically searching for a solution for the Italian language.

Thanks

Comment: Afaik libreoffice can do that.

Comment: > "Afaik libreoffice can do that"

See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/204089/is-it-possible-to-set-libreoffice-to-automatically-split-a-word-at-end-of-linebeginning-of-next/

It works for English, not for Italian :-(

Comment: That is sad. I've seen libreoffice doing that for languages with 1/6 so many native speakers than Italian. Finché vivi, c'è speranza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latex is capable of doing this, if you are willing to go that route. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Il contratto di trasporto concluso ai sensi delle Condizioni Generali,
di norma, è relativo all’utilizzo da parte del passeggero di un singolo
treno ed è rappresentato da un titolo di viaggio che legittima il
medesimo ad usufruire del servizio ferroviario prescelto.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of resulting pdf]

(text taken from travel conditions of [trenitalia](https://www.trenitalia.com/it/informazioni/condizioni_generaliditrasporto.html))

Note that of course the editor does not do the wrapping - you write whole words -, but it is done during compiling the resulting pdf.